# Simple Authentication for On premise Sharepoint 2013 Xamarin.Android app without using Windows Azure

Tags: android, authentication, mobile, xamarin, xamarin.android

Being a beginner to mobile development I am trying to build an xamarin.android app which has to retrieve contents namely lists, news feeds, libraries and all the sites from an On premise Sharepoint 2013 Internet website.

After refering to forums and couple of  websites I understand we can fetch all these data by using REST Api calls. But before that I need to authenticate to the sharepoint site. According to my understanding we need to authenticate using OAuth which needs Windows Azure or any third party identity provider. Is there any other simple way of authenticating (For example just pass user name and password) and connect to the sharepoint site?

Thank you for your patience to read such lengthly post. Could anyone help me with any samples or reference? Appreciate your help

Comment: Threre is one way to authenticate. you can open login in web view and then get cookies when user login. and save it in sharedpreference

Comment: Did you get solution for this?